# backbone method in java trees

Tags: java, tree, nullpointerexception, binary-tree

I'm trying to write a vine method/backbone method in java but it doesn't seem like I'm doing it correctly because I got a run time error.

Here is what I did so far:

```
public void vine() {
  class<T> p = new class<T>(), tmp, prev;
 tmp = root;
 while(tmp != null)
 {
  if( tmp.left != null )
   {
     prev = tmp.right;
    tmp.right = prev.left;
      prev.left = tmp;
   tmp = tmp;  
  }
  else
  {
    tmp = tmp.right;
}


}
 }
```

the run time error seems to be at this line:   tmp.right = prev.left;

Can someone help?

Comment: What specifically is the runtime error?

Comment: java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: "tmp = tmp;" doesn't make much sense.

Comment: I want to set tmp to the child that just become a parent
Isn't it going to be tmp? I tried this as well :   root = tmp;
and it didn't work too

Answer (score 0):

Probably tmp.right is null at

```
prev = tmp.right;
```

Then you'll get a NPE on

```
tmp.right = prev.left;
```

Your code's missing what "root" actually is.

Comment: I wrote this  tmp = root; at the beginning